# Can Reed-Solomon become completely immune to wrong transmissions by using (255,1)?

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, cryptography

With Reed Solomon encoding, N parity bytes enable to detect up to N corrupted bytes among those received, including the parity bytes themselves. Does that mean that if we transmit 254 bytes of parity for only one byte of payload, and add a CRC check inside the byte, the transmission is virtually flawless? Is it done in applications where high datarate is of no importance?

Comment: You can't add a CRC check inside a byte for the usual meaning of CRC as being a Cyclic Redundancy Check; CRCs are usually 12 or 16 or 24 or 32 bits long and your eight-bit byte would swell to more than double its length. Be that as it may, NO code can be "completely immune" to errors in transmission because errors _can_ change one valid transmission into another: a _very very unlikely_ event but by no means an impossible event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this, but it no longer deserves to be called a Reed–Solomon code. An $(n,1)$ Reed–Solomon code is more commonly known as the $n=255$ [repetition code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repetition_code): it repeats the single data byte $255$ times.

This is not *completely* immune to wrong transmissions (nothing is). However, you can detect a wrong transmission unless there is an error in every byte, and that error is the same in every byte, so it is practically immune.

Nobody actually does this.